# Temporary movieclip container as3

Tags: actionscript-3, containers, movieclip, temporary

suppose I have several objects of type MovieClip on my stage and when `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event fires on stage, I want all these objects to become children of newly created Movieclip. So a pseudo code would look like this:

1. When mouse_down happens, REMOVE the objects from the stage (`removeChild`?)
2. Create a new MovieClip and add it to the stage.
3. Add all the objects which were removed in step 1 to the newly created movieclip.

Any guidelines to this? thanks.

Comment: Did you try implementing your 1,2,3 steps? Sounds like it will work, and you probably don't even need to call removeChild, just call newMovieClip.addChild for all the movieclips and they will be removed from the other parent.

Comment: @Baris Usakli I actually tried it before without much luck, but i'm doing it right now again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var newMc:MovieClip;
function downEvent(e:MouseEvent){

    newMc = new MovieClip(); // create new MC

    newMc.addChild(the_old_movieClips);// add old MCs to the new MC

    stage.addChild(newMc); // add newMc to the stage
}
function getBack(){
    stage.addChild(the_old_movieClips);
    removeChild(newMc);
}
```

do not remove child, using `addchild` will make old movieclip as child of the new one

Comment: They will stay invisible with this code, I don't think there is need to set visible to false.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to put them in one container is Scaling. Sort of Zoom in / Zoom out function. Zooming them separately does not give required results, and therefore i need to scale the container instead, and then remove the container and add the objects back to the stage